# Get Full Path of File from Process in C#?

Tags: c#

```
private static string getPath(object id11)
    {
        string wmiQuery = string.Format("select CommandLine from Win32_Process where ProcessId={0}", id11);
        using (ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(wmiQuery))
        {
            using (ManagementObjectCollection retObjectCollection = searcher.Get())
            {
                foreach (ManagementObject retObject in retObjectCollection)
                {
                    if (retObject["CommandLine"] != null)
                    {
                         string s= (string.Format("[{0}]", retObject["CommandLine"]));
                        string k = s.Substring(s.IndexOf("EXE")+4);
                        k = k.Remove(k.IndexOf("]"));
                        return k;
                    }
                    return null;
                }
                return null;
            }
        }
```

I use this code to get the notepad full path. This code is work fine when notepad file is open using double click. But When i open file inside notepad like (File->Open)... than this code not work to get a full path. Is there any way to find the path of file open like this. And one more thing i need file path not notepad Executable Path. Or suggest me some other solutions.

Comment: So you are looking for the full path of a document opened in another program, like notepad, using a menu inside that application? Seems impossible to me since you will need knowledge of the inner workings and that information needs to be exposed by that application. The title of the question is a bit misleading since you are not looking for the path of the process.

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. What use case do you have that caused you to want to know which file is open in Notepad? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: This used to work back in the olden days of OLE, programs would publish the document they had opened with a "moniker", found by iterating the Running Object Table.  OLE is dead, expired, pushing up the daisies, gone to make its maker, it is a dead parrot.  You cannot make this work unless you know a *lot* about the process or it is willing to co-operate somehow.

Comment: @CodeCaster i want to create employee monitoring application. Its my final year project. So i want to monitor all the activity which employee perform during working hours.

Comment: This isn't trivial, read Hans's comment. You could try to write a file system filter driver to monitor all files that are opened, of that fulfills your requirements. Or consider not reinventing the wheel and buying software that already does this.

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks at the command line arguments sent to a process. As you have rightly found, when you double click a file (.txt or .doc), it may be send as command line argument to the file. Your solution rightly finds the file in those cases.

But, when you open the file from the application, there is no command line argument.

One way is to use a tool like [Handle](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/handle.aspx) to get the list of process which has your file open.

Sample screen shot:

[image]

You can use the [Process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process?view=netframework-4.7) class to run it and parse the output.

Certain processes (like notepad) will NOT lock the file. So, this tool will not give you the names of those files.

Comment: Thanks. Any other possible solution. Here i am only mention notepad but i need to work for all applications like (window photo viewer, vlc player...)